# Angular Reactive Form inputs are empty after using *ngIf directive

Tags: angular, forms, rxjs

I am new to angular and I am trying to implement a reactive form. I will only put a few lines of code so it will be more easy to follow. I have a parent component:

```
page: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addProjectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
         projectId: ['', Validators.required],
         projectName: [''],
         startDate: [''],
         user: [this.user.email],
         country: ['', Validators.required],
         projectType: [this.projectTypeValue, Validators.required],
      });
    this.page = 1;
  }

  clickNext() {
    this.page = this.page + 1;
  }

  clickBack() {
     this.page = this.page - 1;
  }
```

In the parent html I have two child components:

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-body id="first-page" *ngIf="page === 1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="projectType" class="label">Bid / Delivery Product</label>
      <nb-select class="select-column" (selectedChange)="saveProjectType();ngOnInit()"
                 id="projectType" formControlName="projectType">
        <nb-option value="bid">Bid</nb-option>
        <nb-option value="deliveryProduct">Delivery Product</nb-option>
      </nb-select>
    </div>
    <delivery-template *ngIf="this.addProjectForm.value.projectType == 'deliveryProduct'"
                       [deliveryProjectForm]="addProjectForm"></delivery-template>
    <bid-template *ngIf="this.addProjectForm.value.projectType == 'bid'"
                             [bidProjectForm]="addProjectForm"></bid-template>
  </nb-card-body>
  <nb-card-body id="second-page" *ngIf="page === 2">
    <!-- some data -->
  </nb-card-body>
  <nb-card-body id="third-page" *ngIf="page === 3">
    <!-- some data -->
  </nb-card-body>
  <nb-card-footer>
    <button nbButton [disabled]="page === 3 || !addProjectForm.valid" class="btn float-left ml-2"
            type="button" (click)="clickNext()">Next
    </button>
    <button nbButton [disabled]="page === 1"
            type="button" (click)="clickBack()">Go Back
    </button>
    <button nbButton [disabled]="page !== 3"
            type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Save
    </button>
  </nb-card-footer>
</nb-card>
```

On the child components (bid-template and delivery template) I am passing the addProjectForm:

```
// Only showing delivery-template because bid-template is almost the same
@Input() deliveryProjectForm: FormGroup;


 ngOnInit() {
   if (this.deliveryProjectForm.contains('projectid')) {
      this.deliveryProjectForm.setControl('projectid', new FormControl('',  Validators.required));
    } else {
      this.deliveryProjectForm.addControl('projectid', new FormControl('',  Validators.required));
    }
    // same for the rest of the properties
 }

 // getters

 get projectId() {
    return this.deliveryProjectForm.get('projectid');
  }
  // same for the rest of the properties
```

And on delivery-template html:

```
<form [formGroup]="deliveryProjectForm">
 <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="project_id" class="label">Project ID</label>
        <input
          nbInput id="project_id"
          type="text" class="form-control"
          placeholder="Project ID"
          formControlName="projectid">
        <div *ngIf="projectId.invalid && (projectId.dirty || projectId.touched)" class="text-danger">
          <small *ngIf="projectId.errors.required">
            Project ID is required!
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Same for the rest of properties -->
  
</form>
```

With the form valid and all the fields completed clicking Next and then clicking Back() to the input fields every input field is empty even tough in the debugger addProjectForm has the previous entered values. But the problem is that deliveryProjectForm has empty values after going back. If I am using [hidden] instead of *ngIf the values are restored. Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When NgIf expression evaluates to false, element it's attached to (in this case component) gets removed from DOM. Then when NgIf expression evaluates to true again, completely new component instance is created. And `ngOnInit` is called for **this** instance. And inside `ngOnInit` you reset control values. `hidden` attribute doesn't remove element from DOM, that's why control value remains unchanged when using it.